# Tableview doesn't display data in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7

I'm working on the tableView in swift 2.2 in xcode 7.3.1 and I'm sure from my code because it's not the first time for me to deal with tableView , I'm pulling data correctly from server and stored it in array but I notice the two function that is related to table view is not called so the table view appear empty for me ! I added cell and linked tableview with view also from layout.

I don't know where is the problem!

```
class studentTeacherList: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var studentParentTable: UITableView!


@IBOutlet weak var loadIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!




var username:String!
var fromSender: String?
var toRec: String?

var student_id = [Int]()
var parent_id = [String]()
var student_names = [String]()
var parent_name = [String]()



//Sent Data
var s_id:Int = 0
var s_name = ""
var p_id = ""
var p_name = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    studentParentTable.delegate = self
    studentParentTable.dataSource = self


    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    username = prefs.objectForKey("user")as! String
    fromSender = prefs.objectForKey("Sender")as! String
    toRec = prefs.objectForKey("Receiver")as! String


    self.loadIndicator.startAnimating()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

       self.loadList()
       //self.studentParentTable.reloadData()


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
    });


    studentParentTable.reloadData()

}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return student_names.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //This method to define each cell at Table View
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")


    cell.textLabel?.text = student_names[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parent_name[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )

}



func loadList()
{
    var normallink = "mylinkhere"
    normallink = normallink + "?teacherid=" + self.username



    var studentParentURL:NSURL = NSURL (string: normallink)!
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: studentParentURL)!



    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)

        if let alldata = json["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for onedata in alldata {
                if let stu_id = onedata["id"] as? Int {
                    student_id.append(stu_id)
                }
                if let stu_name = onedata["studentName"] as? String {
                    student_names.append(stu_name)
                }
                if let par_id = onedata["parentId"] as? String {
                    parent_id.append(par_id)
                }
                if let par_name = onedata["parentName"] as? String {
                    parent_name.append(par_name)
                }



            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error Serializing JSON: \(error)")
    }




    print(student_names.count)

}


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    s_id = student_id[indexPath.row]
    s_name = student_names[indexPath.row]
    p_id = parent_id[indexPath.row]
    p_name = parent_name[indexPath.row]
 }
}
```

Comment: Try moving the reloadData() call to after `self.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()`

Comment: @WMios yes it's working now thank you for your note :)

Comment: @WMios I updated something in my post to store value when click on each row in table view but it gives me out of index

Comment: you should ask that as a separate question. Please up vote my answer here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't reloading after this call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

       self.loadList()
       //self.studentParentTable.reloadData()


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
    });
```

So you should add `studentParentTable.reloadData()` after `self.loadIndicator.stopAnimating()`.